# About Listing NSURLCache url and deleting item cache

Tags: ios, url, caching, restful-url, nsurlcache

I working on a RestFull api and i would like to test some powerful thing. To avoid always calling the server i cache some return data with `NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad`. I delete my cache with   `[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];` . What i would like it's to remove the concern url not all. So is there a way to List all URL and delete one ?